# Just advice for my phd thesis template in lualatex

Tags: luatex, templates

I use this template, I just want some advises for load order or any incompatibility, suggestions (I'm french and I have a bad english, sorry)

```
\documentclass  [                                       % Classe du document
                a4paper,                                % Format papier
                12pt,                                   % Taille de la police de texte
                table,                                  % table de xcolor pour les tables en couleur
                ]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}                       % Commandes mathématiques
\usepackage{fontspec}                                       % Encodage et prise en charge des polices
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}                         % Paramétrage de la langue générale
\usepackage{graphicx}                                       % Permet d'inclure des images
\usepackage{xspace}                                         % Espace en fin de macro, sauf si ponctuation
\usepackage{microtype}                                      % Microtypographie pour la justification parfaite
\usepackage{booktabs}                                       % Tableaux officiels et plus simple
\usepackage{siunitx}                                        % Unités
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[                                                % Définition des marges
    top=2cm,                                                % Marge haute
    bottom=2.7cm,                                           % Marge basse
    inner=2.2cm,                                            % Marge intérieure
    outer=3cm]{geometry}                                    % Marge marge extérieure
\usepackage{imakeidx}                                       % Index
\usepackage[
    breaklinks=true,
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=violet, 
    citecolor=blue, 
    urlcolor=blue,
    pdfencoding=unicode]{hyperref}                          % Hyperliens automatiques
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[french, nameinlink]{cleveref}                   % Controle des liens
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    sorting=none,
    url=false,
    isbn=false]{biblatex}                                   % Bonne bibliographie
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}                           % Personnalisation des titres
\usepackage[french,intoc]{nomencl}                          % Nomenclature
\usepackage{ifthen}                                         % Conditions boléennes pour les groupes nomencl
\usepackage{import}                                         % Importer un fichier latex dans le fichier maître
\usepackage{pdfpages}                                       % Inclure des PDF en annexe
\usepackage{eurosym}                                        % Symbole euro
\usepackage{pdflscape}                                      % Mettre des éléments en paysage
\usepackage{pgfplots}                                       % Tracer des courbes directement avec Latex
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}                                  % Utiliser des tables avec pgf
\usepackage{pgf-pie}                                        % Faire des diagrammes circulaires
\usepackage{enumitem}                                       % Customiser les listes
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{tocbibind}                                      % Table des matières et biblio dans le sommaire
\usepackage{caption}                                        % Hyperliens qui renvoient au bon endroit
\usepackage{multicol}                                       % Texte ou listes sur plusieurs colonnes
\usepackage{tabularx}                                       % largeur de colonne auto dans les tables avec X
\usepackage{makecell}                                       % Redefinir une cellule dans un tableau
\usepackage{subcaption}                                     % Plusieurs graphiques sur une seule figure
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{spelling}
\usepackage[european, siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lua-widow-control}
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at the yathesis class. Over at texnique.fr this seem to a widely used thesis template.

Comment: That being said, you should load `hyperref` after most of the other packages. There are just very few exceptions such as cleveref.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some comments, in no particular order:

- Since `amssymb` loads `amsfonts` automatically, there's no need to load `amsfonts` explicitly.
- Your code doesn't appear to load the `xcolor` package, even though the `table` document class-level option would indicate that you meant to load `xcolor` as well. (Specifically, if the `xcolor` package is loaded with the option `table`, the `colortbl` package gets loaded in a way that maximizes its interoperability with the `xcolor` package.)
- No need to specify the `breaklinks=true` option when loading `hyperref`. Same for `pdfencoding=unicode`.
- Are you sure you need the `bookmark` package?
- You would do well to load the `xurl` package (to allow line breaks at arbitrary points in a long URL string).
- Your code loads the `fontspec` package but doesn't contain any `\set....font` directives. Is this intentional? Does your document maybe utilize the default fonts (Latin Modern and Computer Modern)?
- Do consider loading the `csquotes` package with an explicit choice for the French-language quoting style. The four relevant options are `french=guillemets`, `french=guillemets*`, `french=quotes`, and `french=quotes*`. Please see section 10.9 of the manual of the `csquotes` package for more information on what these options do.
- Try loading `hyperref` and `cleveref` *last*.
- Not knowing what's in the body of the document, it's not possible to tell whether or not many of the packages that are loaded in the preamble are actually needed. For instance, your code loads the `ntheorem` package but doesn't contain any `\newtheorem` directives. This leads me to surmise that maybe `ntheorem` isn't needed at all. Only you can make the final determination in this matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :)